# How to create LINK POST with API

Tags: facebook, post, hyperlink, adsmanager

do you know if its possible to create a square link post without ads manager? With some html code, java or api?

I've checked various forums, but I can't find anything

Comment: Are you asking about the thumbnail image format? That largely gets decided by Facebook itself. You can try and supply only a small 200px * 200px image as your og:image, as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images explains, then it _might_ do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Im talking about this one:  https://dribbble.com/shots/3798789-Facebook-Post-Link-and-Image-Sketch-Template/attachments/10026469?mode=media thanks for the tip, I'll check it out :)

Comment: So that would be a normal, run-of-the-mill link post, with the link thumbnail having the recommended dimensions. What is the _actual_ question here, to to make posts via API? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#publish, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing#publish-a-page-post

Comment: Posting via API is only possible for pages (and groups, if your app gets installed into the group by a group admin) though - onto user profiles, that is not possible any more, that has been removed ages ago. For user posts, you can only use one of the dialogs Facebook provides, to let them _actively_ share your link onto their profile.